# Does ' have an effect in special forms in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, quote

Will `'` affect the evaluation of special forms?  Example: `(function 'function-name)`.  If this doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'name is read to (quote name).

[FUNCTION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm) expects a name for a function, a list (setf some-name) or a lambda expression.

(quote name) is neither. So it is an error to use it.

Comment: This makes sense. Besides, what's the difference between `name` and `(quote name)`?

Comment: PI evaluates to 3.141592653589793D0 and 'PI evaluates to PI. PI is read as PI and 'PI is read as 'PI, which is the same as (QUOTE PI).